# Minidump generated by WER, but no stack trace is available

Tags: c#, wpf, stack, trace, windows-error-reporting

I have a WPF application written in C# that I built which crashed on a colleagues machine. Luckily he set Windows Error Reporting up to generate minidumps when a crash occurs. He sent me his .exe, his .pdb, and his .dmp. I put them all in the same directory and opened the .dmp from that location in Visual Studio 2013. I added in symbols from Microsoft Symbol Servers and then tried to Debug with Mixed, but although the debugger launches, I don't see anything. Usually on crash dumps I get a stack trace or something, but the debugger literally doesn't show anything - no threads, nothing.

The application is an x64 WPF application using 3rd party DLLs like RadControls for WPF, etc. and the exception code is 0xC0000005. It says Heap Information is Not Present.

Is there anything I can do to view more information about my error or at least ensure some stack tracing is available next time this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation for my Winforms application, here are the steps I took to get a dump with stack trace.

1. [Turned on Windows Error Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps). Ensured that the DumpType is set to generate Full dumps.
2. In the program code, turned off Application Framework in Project Settings and created custom entry class.
3. Added the line `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);` to `Main()`

Now if the application has an unhandled exception, it crashes and creates a dump file which can be opened and debugged.

*Note:* This still doesn't point to the right line for user-raised exceptions, but it DOES work for exceptions generated by the application.